# how to change direction of input search datatable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to use jQuery DataTable in Arabic language and have a few questions:

1. how to change direction input datatable in jquery
2. how to change language to arabic in datatable
3. how to change direction of paging in datatable

Using

```
//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js
//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
//cdn.datatables.net/plugins/1.10.7/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js
```

```
$(function () {
    $('#liveSearch').dataTable();
});
```

Comment: 4) [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

> **SOLUTION**

Add `dir="rtl"` to `html` tag as follows:

```
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">
```

Use the following code to include Arabic translations

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var table = $('#liveSearch').DataTable({
        "language": {
            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/i18n/Arabic.json"
        }
     });
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rwh6h3ny/1/) for code and demonstration.